# Why does my JavaScripted Google Map look different than the public one?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Please view this map first:
[Google Map](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.1801283,-111.6905245,2688a,35y,76.96t/data=!3m1!1e3)

Next, put this code into a new .htm file and view it in the same browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100%; width: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100%; width: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.16"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.2956686,-111.7006661),
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
        map.setTilt(45);
      };
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas" />
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is, why does the Google Map have more tilt degree options and even a tilt icon, but the map I created with the Google Map JavaScript API does not tilt that way at that zoom level?  My Manager wants me to create something like the Google Map linked in this post, not the one I created using the Google Map JavaScript API.  What API should I be using?  I've tried examining the Google Map JavaScript code and there is too much for me to comprehend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Google Maps and Google Maps API v3 are mantained by different teams and have different goals. Google Maps aims to end users while Google Maps API aims to developers. Moreover,  Google wants to keep an edge in favour of their plattform so no developer steals the casual users from Google Maps.

Besides, rolling out new functionalities in google maps it's easier than integrating them in the API, with all the documentation an syntax hierarchy they must observe. They just need to include the new code as a plugin, while in turn the Google Maps API library must integrate everything in its core.

Some of those functionalities do make their way over to google maps API. Some of them don't.